# Memtest86+ errors. Anything to do about it?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

I have the following results during a memtest86+ execution. I've identified which stick is faulty by running the test with only one stick at the time.

[image: memtest results]

Is there something I can do about this faulty ram stick ? Is it ok to go along with it anyway ? Considering the surge in RAM demand (and price) I am looking for any solution...

Thanks.

Comment: " I am looking for any solution." Get the module replaced under warranty.  If the warranty has expired then replace the module.  "Is there something I can do about this faulty ram stick?" - You simply replace the module

Comment: Just be aware: as far as I know memtest86+ hasn't been updated for DDR4, and may give false positives. Try memtest86 (from https://www.memtest86.com/) to get a 2nd opinion. As per what Ramhound said, in general once you get _any_ error in a RAM stick it is bad and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RAM is bad.  Stop using it.

> Is there something I can do about this faulty ram stick ?

Yes.  The Linux kernel can be patched to try to avoid just the reported segments of RAM.

> Is it ok to go along with it anyway ?

No.  I absolutely do not trust a chip that has even one error.  Errors may be more prone to spread.

Furthermore, if you care about your data, you really need to stop using the computer for this.

This might not be as much of an issue if you only use your computer to display video on a TV, and if the video streams are stored elsewhere, and the most likely scenario of problems is that some graphics get corrupted (which may be hardly noticeable in a video stream).

However, if this computer stores data locally, or has access to write data remotely, then you're really risking data corruption.  Such data corruption can often be hard to detect, and is not easily reversible (the best way is to restore from backup, if you have a trusted backup).

So, if you value the data on this computer at all, get rid of the bad RAM.

There are also possibilities of system instability (where the system could lock up or freeze), which may be another reason not to gamble with such memory.

I strongly recommend that you stop using the memory, even if you cannot afford another memory chip right away.  (If you have other memory, I'd feel much more comfortable having a slow system that may have some other limitations, and not think that my data is being corrupted.)

Congratulations on being able to identify which RAM stick is the problem.  I mean that comment seriously.  Sometimes that's actually pretty hard to do, since some computers will act in not-easy-to-predict ways when you do things like moving RAM chips to different spots.  So things could be worse: You actually seem better off than what some people endure when they find bad RAM chips.

Comment: I discuss this a bit further at [TOOGAM's answer to The Gaming Grunts's superuser.com question: "Is the RAM in my computer failing?"](https://superuser.com/a/1025974/401839)  (I won't repeat it all here, unnecessarily creating even more redundancy.)

Comment: Thanks for your (very) complete answer. Guess I'll have to do without that stick for a while.